# How To Use ListIterator to Edit a List Content

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator

I'm using a `ListIterator` to iterate over a list of some object. The goal is to edit the contents of the list.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three","Four","Five"));
        ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator();
        String current ;
        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            doSomething(listIterator); 
            current = listIterator.next();
            //here I Want that current has the same value  as it was Before The doSomething Call
            //or in other Word , i want to save the adress of the last visired object In the List before doSomething Call.
    //As a result i can iterate from this point in the List.
            }

        }

    private static ListIterator<String> doSomething(ListIterator<String> listIterator) {
        System.out.println("Dosomething " + listIterator.next()); //
        System.out.println("Dosomething " + listIterator.next()); //
        System.out.println("Dosomething " + listIterator.next()); //
        System.out.println("Dosomething " + listIterator.next()); //
        return listIterator;
    }
}
```

Could you please give me some insight?

I'm using `ListIterator` because I want to go forth and back in the list, and for editing purposes.

Comment: Only `doSomething` knows what it's doing with the `ListIterator`, so it is up to it to make sure the `ListIterator` is in the same place on exit as it was on entry, e.g. by calling `previous()` four times.

Comment: Thank You for your Help , is there another idea ? like saving the current state before the dosomething Call?+ do you think that listiterator is still good for my purpose or i had to jump to another structure?

Comment: You can't save the state of an iterator, nor close/copy it. You should already know this if you had **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListIterator` keeps track of the current index, so you can save it and rewind after you call `doSomething`:

```
int pos = listIterator.nextIndex();
doSomething(listIterator);
while (listIterator.nextIndex() > pos) {
    listIterator.previous();
}
```

This assumes that `doSomething` only advances the iterator.